# Why does the list index not reset after I remove a block?

Tags: python, loops

The question reads as follows:

Every maximal block of k consecutive digits with k>1 scores 10**(k-2) points for that block. A block of two digits thus scores one point, three digits score ten points, four digits score a hundred points, and so on. However, a special rule is in effect saying that whenever a block of digits lies at the lowest end of the number, that block scores double the points it would score in any other position. This function should compute the meaningfulness score of the given positive integer n as the sum of its individual block scores.

```
def duplicate_digit_bonus(n):
  num = str(n)
  if len(num) == 1:
    return 0
  digit = num[0]
  new_len, old_len, score = len(num), len(num), 0
  while new_len != 0:
    block_len = 0
    for i in range(len(num)):
      if num[i] != digit:
        digit = num[i]
        new_len = old_len - block_len
        old_len = new_len
        num = num[block_len:]
        if block_len >= 2:
            score = score + 10**(block_len - 2)
      else:
        block_len += 1
    
  return score
```

While I haven't addressed the duplicate points at the end, how do I make sure the index resets when i read through the new_block. It continues from the previous loop.

Comment: Don't use a `for` loop, because those overwrite the counter variable with the next element of the iterable you're iterating over. Use a `while` loop and manually control the counter.

Comment: Note that in the interest of helping people easily understand what you're asking, it would be very helpful if you added some explanation of your code and specified what you mean by _"list index"_: is it the variable `i`? Also, consider creating a [mre]: resetting the counter in a loop has nothing to do with the rest of your algorithm, and you could create a MRE that is much more concise and clear.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I don't get the idea of your algorithm.
Maybe you can get some value from this approach:

```
def f (n):
    scores = []
    length = 1
    for i in range (1, len(n)):
        if n[i-1] < n[i]:
            length += 1
        else:
            scores.append (length)
            length = 1

    scores.append (length)
    return sum([10 ** (k - 2) for k in scores if k >= 2])

print ( f ([1,2,3,4,1,2]) )
```

Result:

```
101
```